# Two variable trigonometric inequality

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

Let $x>3$ and $k>0$ be both reals. I want to show algebraically that
If $k\in(0,1)$, then $k\cot(x)>\cot(\frac{x}{k})$.  If $k>1$, then $k\cot(x)<\cot(\frac{x}{k})$.It is clear that the expression is $0$ if $k=1$. Graphically and with Taylor expansion at infinity I can see it, but I was trying to prove this algebraically. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If $k\cot(x)-\cot(\frac{x}{k})>0$ then $k\cot(-x)-\cot(\frac{-x}{k})<0$.

Comment: This is because $sin(-x)=-sin(-x)$, but I do not quite understand how does it help.

Comment: This means you need to edit your question because it's not clear what you are asking

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: For example, let $k=2$. Then $2\cot(x)-\cot(\frac{x}{2})$ has period $2\pi$. Find $x$ such that $2\cot(x)-\cot(\frac{x}{2})<0$, then $2\cot(-x)-\cot(\frac{-x}{2})>0$. Find integer $n$ such that $-x+2n\pi>3$. Then $2\cot(-x+2n\pi)-\cot(\frac{-x+2n\pi}{2})>0$. So it's false